# Spyder unable to load extension pydevd_plugin_pandas_types

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plugins, ipython, spyder

Unsing Spyder I receive the following error when starting the IDE:

```
Python 3.7.15 (default, Nov 24 2022, 21:12:53) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.31.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Unable to load extension: pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types
```

What is the cause and how to fix this issue?

[image]

```
* Spyder version: 5.3.3  (conda)
* Python version: 3.7.15 64-bit
* Qt version: 5.15.2
* PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
* Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same probelm ,my solution was updating spyder to latest version that is 5.4.2 and activate conda environment that you set in spyder and run conda install spyder-kernels=2.4 again.hope this help

Comment: Using your second command I receive: ```UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment...```.

Answer (score 1):

The UnsatisfiableError error message typically indicates that the package you are trying to install (in this case, spyder-kernels=2.4) has a dependency that conflicts with another package or version of Python already installed in your environment.

Here are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

Make sure you have activated the correct conda environment before running the conda install command. You can do this by running conda activate <env_name> in your terminal or Anaconda prompt.

1.Try updating your existing packages before installing spyder-kernels=2.4. You can do this by running conda update --all in your terminal or Anaconda prompt.

2.Try creating a new conda environment specifically for Spyder and its dependencies. You can create a new environment with the necessary Python version and install Spyder and other packages using the following commands:

```
conda create -n spyder_env python=3.8
conda activate spyder_env
conda install spyder=5.0
```

This will create a new environment called spyder_env with Python 3.8 and install Spyder 5.0.

3.If none of the above works, try removing the existing environment and creating a new one from scratch. You can remove an environment with the command conda remove --name <env_name> --all. Just be aware that this will remove all packages and dependencies in the environment.

Hopefully one of these solutions will help resolve the UnsatisfiableError you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out in the next days.

Comment: This did not work for me...

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: I had some weird dependency issues and conflicts with PyQt6. This may be specific to the platform I am using (Debian 10). However, I cannot reconstruct the issue since I purged the complete Anaconda installation.

Comment: However, thank you for the hint with virtual environments. I should use these more often.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me. I use anaconda as well but attempting to install/update spyder through anaconda generally gave me issues. So I use pip and it worked like a charm.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip uninstall spyder
sudo pip install spyder==5.4.2
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and come back to you.

Comment: Sorry this did not work either...

Answer (score 0):

I somehow could not get things working using the suggested answers.

Fixed it now by installing a completely new Anaconda distribution:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue. Just close (X) Console 1/A and everything works fine in Console 2/A.

Comment: This was my workaround but still an issue. I expect my IDE to start without any errors.