# setting Jupyter kernel on different place

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have a question about setting up a kernel for jupyter notebook.

I usually did

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name {conda env name} --display-name "{displayed env name}"
```

However, it seems that because my conda environment is saved in a different location as  below shows, it cannot find my environment.

```
(CL_MRI) 1406% [x2519a02@skl05 x2519a02]$ conda env list 
# conda environments:
#
base                     /apps/applications/PYTHON/3.7
jupyterhub_v1            /apps/applications/PYTHON/3.7/envs/jupyterhub_v1
jupyterhub_v1_bk         /apps/applications/PYTHON/3.7/envs/jupyterhub_v1_bk
kisti-jhub01             /apps/applications/PYTHON/3.7/envs/kisti-jhub01
neuron-jupyter           /apps/applications/PYTHON/3.7/envs/neuron-jupyter
CL_MRI                *  /scratch/x2519a02/.conda/envs/CL_MRI
```

(this is the error I get)

```
(CL_MRI) 1406% [x2519a02@skl05 x2519a02]$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name CL_MRI --display-name "CL_MRI"
Unable to load extension: pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types
Installed kernelspec CL_MRI in /home01/x2519a02/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/cl_mri
```

Is there a way to specify the exact location of the conda environment path?

Comment: It seems to be a similar issues mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409693/spyder-unable-to-load-extension-pydevd-plugin-pandas-types) maybe you could try using the suggested approach by install/upgrade different conda distribution or upgrade Jupyter if it's using older version?